# Iterate over dynamically added instance variables

Tags: ruby

I've got a simple connection class with "dynamically" added instance variables.

```
class Connection
  def self.add_connection_variable name
    define_method name do
      # some logic here
      instance_variable_get "@#{name}"
    end

    define_method "#{name}=" do |value|
      instance_variable_set "@#{name}", value
    end
  end

  add_connection_variable :timeout
  add_connection_variable :protocol
end
```

After creating a new connection object

`connection = Connection.new`

I want to iterate over added variables as soon as new instance is been created via `Connection.new`. I've tried to use `connection.instance_variables` but it always returns empty array `[]`. Is there any way to iterate over those variables?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem: `c = Connection.new; c.timeout = 42; c.protocol = :http; c.instance_variables #=> [:@timeout, :@protocol]`. Are you sure you actually added the instance variables?

Comment: If you don't call `c.timeout=`, then `instance_variables` will not return `:@timeout` even though it has been added through `add_connection_variable`. This is what I presume he means. Would explain what he observes. @anton, want to clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by "then `instance_variables` will not return `:@timeout` even though it has been added through `add_connection_variable`"? `add_connection_variable` doesn't add an instance variable, it adds a method.

Comment: @JörgWMittag as @SiimLiiser mentioned there is a problem when I try to iterate over this variables just after new instance been created. So until I use `c.timeout=` there will be no :@timeout in `c.instance_variables`. I've added more details to the question to clarify it

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Before you call `timeout=`, there *is no instance variable* to iterate over, so the behavior is entirely consistent with what you want. You want to iterate over the variables. There are no variables. Ergo, you iterate over no variables. The behavior matches your specification exactly.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Keep your own list of the added methods

```
class Connection
  def self.connection_variables
    @connection_variables ||= []
  end

  def self.add_connection_variable name
    connection_variables << name

    define_method name do
      # some logic here
      instance_variable_get "@#{name}"
    end

    define_method "#{name}=" do |value|
      instance_variable_set "@#{name}", value
    end
  end
end
```